# How to solve "error: bad operand types for binary operator" problem?

Tags: java

the program aims to check the first element of any user String
then, check if it is "Capital letter" or "number from 2 to 9 "

```
import java.util.*;
public class test1
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      Scanner mykey= new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first sentence");
      String firstSen= mykey.nextLine();
      String firstChar= firstSen.substring(0,1);
      if ((firstChar <='Z') && (firstChar >= 'A'))
         {System.out.println("Its a letter");}
      else if ((firstChar>='2') && (firstChar<='9'))
         {System.out.println("Its a number");}
   }
}
```

the errors

```
test1.java:10: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
      if ((firstChar <='Z') && (firstChar >= 'A'))
                     ^
  first type:  String
  second type: char
test1.java:10: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
      if ((firstChar <='Z') && (firstChar >= 'A'))
                                          ^
  first type:  String
  second type: char
test1.java:12: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
      else if ((firstChar>='2') && (firstChar<='9'))
                         ^
  first type:  String
  second type: char
test1.java:12: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
      else if ((firstChar>='2') && (firstChar<='9'))
```

Comment: `firstSen.substring(0,1);` returns a substring (which is a string). You want the `charAt(0)` method

Comment: `firstChar` is a `String` and you compare it with `'Z'` which is `char`.

Comment: I think you need the ```charAt``` method. ```char firstChar = firstSen.substring(0, 1).charAt(0);```

Comment: Now I knew the problem
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substring(0, 1)` returns a `String` and your mistake is comparing a `String` to a `char` using `>=` and `<=`.

You should get the first letter of the string, not as a `String`, but as a `char`, by using the `charAt` method:

```
  Scanner mykey= new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter your first sentence");
  String firstSen= mykey.nextLine();
  char firstChar= firstSen.charAt(0); // note this line!
  if ((firstChar <='Z') && (firstChar >= 'A'))
     {System.out.println("Its a letter");}
  else if ((firstChar>='2') && (firstChar<='9'))
     {System.out.println("Its a number");}
```

Two `char`s can be compared with `<=` and `>=`. A `String` and a `char` can't.

Answer (score -1):

The error **bad operand type for operator** appears when you are comparing two operands which are not eligible for comparison using the provided operator. As pointed out already by @Sweeper, you are comparing a String and a char.

Another way to solve your problem can be to compare the ASCII values of the characters you are comparing. Here is an alternative solution.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test1
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      Scanner mykey= new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first sentence");
      String firstSen= mykey.nextLine();
      // Fetch the first character and then convert to int
      // so that the comparison can be don based on ASCII values
      int firstChar = (int) firstSen.charAt(0);
      // ASCII value for A = 65, Z = 90
      if ((firstChar <= 90) && (firstChar >= 65))
         {System.out.println("Its a letter");}
      // ASCII value for 2 = 50, 9 = 57
      else if ((firstChar>= 50) && (firstChar<=57))
         {System.out.println("Its a number");}
   }
}
```

Comment: May I know what is wrong with this answer that it deserves a downvote?

Comment: Your code seems to be the same as Sweeper's, but with all the clear char constants replaced by magic numbers.

Comment: So? That makes the answer unhelpful? Did I take away his credit in this answer? Didn't I clearly call out that this is another approach?

IMHO, this discourages new community members from contributing - such behaviour is not helpful.

Comment: It was just an observation. It wasn't an accusation.